# upload image from react with active storage rails api

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, react-hooks, rails-activestorage

I try to upload image in my react front-end form with active_storage rails (6.+)
I don't understand why my code don't work. I have followed several tutorials but i don't have more result...

I put in my model `has_one_attached :image`, `image` in my `params.require`, in my config `config.active_storage.service = :local`

in my form :

```
...
const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
const handleSubmit = () => {

    let theProduct = {
      "user_id": props.user_id,
      "name": name,
      "category": category,
      "image": image
    }

    ApiService.create(`products`, theProduct)
  }

// in the return
<input type="file" name="image" onChange={e => setImage(e.target.files[0])} />
```

and my storage.yml :

```
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

I forgot some thing ?

EDIT :

```
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  } ;

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <TextField 
          id="name"
          label="Name"
          type="text"
          required
          fullWidth
          {...register('name')}
        />
        <input type="file" {...register('image')} />
        <Button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
```

I don't have `e.target.files[0]` but the value of the input... I'm looking for the solution

Comment: Have you checked so that you're sending the request as `formdata/multipart`? You can't include binary data (files) in `application/json` without going through the steps of converting it to and from a base64 encoded string in the client and server.

Comment: i tried to use formData (use form for react hooks) but i don't understand how i can put `e.target.files[0]`... (i have edited my answer)

Comment: Did you look at using the JS uploader provided by active storage? https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

Comment: Yes I tried but the react active storage don't work for me... My react and my rails api are separated